# Trying to create a batch file to select one random file from a folder and copy to another folder

Tags: batch-file

Very new to batch coding, I have a folder with 1000+ subfolders and i'm trying to use the below to copy one file from each subfolder into a new folder.
both folders are already created.
all are on an external HD
all files are JPEG if relevant.
when executing (double click from explorer) getting: “The system couldn't find the path specified” batch file error
Please help :-(

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd E:\"New folder"
set t=0
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    set /A t+=1
    set n[!t!]=0
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n[!t!]+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
    set /A "rand=(n[!t!]*%random%)/32768+1"
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" E:\samples\"New folder"
    cd..
)
pause
```

Comment: `cd /D "E:\New folder"` and `copy "!file[%rand%]!" "E:\samples\New folder"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`cd E:\"New folder"` to `cd "E:\New folder" or cd "E:\\New folder"`

and, as suggested in the comments, it is a good idea to replace

`for %%f in (*.*) do (` with `for %%f in (*.jpeg *.jpg) do (`

As stated in another comment change also the appropriate line to:

`copy "!file[%rand%]!" "E:\samples\New folder"`

Comment: it runs fine, but gives me the mentioned "error" message

Comment: Huh? `batch` files are executable by default. What "headerline"? No such thing in `batch`.

Comment: Okay, making the
    cd "E:\New folder" or cd "E:\\New folder"
change worked, now i see i have to define the code to only copy image files (jpeg, jpg, etc.)
where do i put that in and how?

Comment: And? Error message about missing path away?

Comment: @Amos: replace `for %%f in (*.*) do (` with `for %%f in (*.jpeg *.jpg) do (`. Add more extensions when needed.

Comment: @Amos: "one more thing" ... that's a topic for another question, isn't it? THIS question has an answer and the answer solves your problem, so accept it as an answer and if you have further issues, ask them as a separate question. The way you try to do it here is a never ending discussion and never ending answering ...

Comment: Got it, new to the forum and it's rules. you are right of course. will post new question. thank you for your help!

Comment: Okay, interesting development that ties directly with this thread.
while 90% of files are copied fine, i am getting many "file location not found" error messages, my guess is this is due to some files with the same names in final folder so, how do i tell it to add a (1),(2),(3) etc to files with duplicate titles?

Comment: One of the main rules in Python (I am mainly in Python) I know is: "in case of ambiguity resist the urge to guess". If I understand you right you don't know why the error messages are coming up and try to guess? "file location not found" doesn't sound for me as the problem is overwriting of files ... Hmmm ...
By the way ... I am erroneously here, because I was too fast reading and assuming you are on Linux doing shell programming where you were on Windows writing batch files ...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    ^^^^^^^ Perhaps you should use "PUSHD" here
    set /A t+=1
    set n[!t!]=0
    ^^^ This set n[1], n[2] etc to 0; increment each directory
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n[!t!]+=1
       ^^^^ Increment filecount in each directory
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
       ^^^^ This will set a variable called "file[]" to the filename
       ^^^^ since n is undefined. n[!t!] is defined; n is not
    )
    set /A "rand=(n[!t!]*%random%)/32768+1"
    ^^ OK - this sets "rand" to a random number.
    ^^ Personally, I'd use "!random!" since that will change for every
    ^^ iteration of %%i. As it stands, it will be replaced by the value
    ^^ of RANDOM at the time "for...%%i..." is parsed, consequently if 2
    ^^ directories have the same number of files and remain unchanged
    ^^ between runs, then the same 2 files will be "paired" on extraction
    ^^ Better in my book is SET /a rand=!random! %% n[!t!] +1
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" E:\samples\"New folder"
    ^^ Well, "file[]" would be selected here as "rand" is not set when 
    ^^ "for...%%i..." is parsed
    cd..
    ^^^^ and "POPD" here
)
```